# Are cv-qualifiers allowed on decltype(auto) variables?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, auto, decltype, c++17

The standard states that

> If the placeholder is the `decltype(auto)` type-specifier, `T` shall be the placeholder alone.
>
> `decltype(auto)*x7d = &i;` // error, declared type is not plain `decltype(auto)`

It is not clear whether cv-qualifiers are still allowed though. It would make sense if they are allowed. Compilers seem to disagree on this matter. The following code [is accepted by g++](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GNdV7wy3YK8xcDyA) but [rejected by clang++](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wu5MsJjymyzNaejO), vc++ does not seem to support `decltype(auto)` variables at all:

```
int main()
{
    const decltype(auto) sz_text{"test"};
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer that, we need to quote the previous paragraph, which specifies what `T` is. In this case, [[dcl.type.auto.deduct]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.auto.deduct#2) says (emphasis mine):

> A type T containing a placeholder type, and a corresponding
>   initializer e, are determined as follows:
>
> - for a variable declared with **a type that contains a placeholder type, T is the declared type of the variable** and e is the
>     initializer. If the initialization is direct-list-initialization, the
>     initializer shall be a braced-init-list containing only a single
>     assignment-expression and e is the assignment-expression;

In this case, `T` is the *whole* declared type of `sz_text`, cv-qualifiers and all. And the paragraph you quoted is quite clear that if it contains `decltype(auto)` as placeholder, it must be that and nothing more.

So a GCC bug. [And an already reported one](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79815).

Comment: Is there an open bug report?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - Not one I was able to find. Not that it is saying much, I'm rarely able to find them without help.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo - This is a rare occasion for me, because I lucked out. [Here it is](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79815). Practically the same.